# Linear Algebra Orthogonality Help

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, real-numbers, orthogonality

I am struggling with this one exercise from self-learning. I simply do not understand what it is asking. If someone could walk me through this problem I would be very grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Put $Y^t=(u,v)$ and calculate:

$$Y·X=u+v≤|Y|=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$$

Interpret geometrically as a region in the $uv$-plane.